# Lebesgue integrability and measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a nonnegative function on the reals. What does the (Lebesgue) measurability of $f$ have to do with the (Lebesgue) integrability of $\int f$? I've spent some time studying the definition at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Integration), and I don't see how measurability enters the equation (other than the fact that it is explicitly mentioned at the start). If $f$ is such that every simple function less than $f$ has integral less than some $x\in\Bbb R$, then $\int f\in\Bbb R$ is defined, regardless of the measurability of $f$. What "essential properties" are lost without the assumption of $f$ being measurable?

*Full discosure: I've [asked this question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716557/defining-the-lebesgue-integral-and-what-is-integrability), but I put too much tangentially-related text on the page, and so probably lost some viewers.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One obvious problem would be the loss of linearity. Consider a nonmeasurable set $A\subseteq\mathbb[0,1]$. Then its outer measure is different from its inner measure, i.e. $\mu_*(A)<\mu^*(A)<\infty$ and 
$$1\ne\mu_*(A)+(1-\mu^*(A))=\int_{[0,1]}\chi_A+\int_{[0,1]}(1-\chi_A)\ne\int_{[0,1]}1=1$$
where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$.

Comment: Actually, $\int-\chi_A=-\int\chi_A$ *by definition*, so that doesn't work (at least, not that easily).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Right, I forgot you first define only for positive. I'll try to correct it.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to say $\int\chi_A+\int\chi_{[0,1]\setminus A}\ne\int\chi_{[0,1]}=1$, where $A\subseteq[0,1]$ is nonmeasurable.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Yep, almost exactly that (I thought about using $1-\chi_A$, now I'm not sure which one to use :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen this layer-cake picture of the idea behind Lebesgue integral? (Taken from Wikipedia):

[image: Riemann vs Lebesgue]

The blue construction is Riemann's integral, the red construction is Lebesgue's integral. Let $f=f(x)$ be the function that you are integrating. Consider the approximation of its integral given by the red rectangles. Each rectangle has area 
$$A_j= y_j \cdot \text{Lenght of }\{ x\in [a, b]\ :\ y_{j-1}< f(x)\le y_j\},$$
where $y_j$ is the vertical position of the upper corners. Measurability of $f$ tells you exactly that the lenght of the set $\{ x\in [a, b]\ :\ y_{j-1}< f(x)\le y_j\}$ is well-defined.

Comment: The definition I am working from uses the supremum of all simple functions dominated by $f$ (I know some other developments use the Riemann integral of the quantity you mention; that's not the definition I'm working with). I think if I translate it into your terms, I am taking the Riemann integral of the "inner" volume of that set, which is well defined even if it is not equal to the "outer" volume.

Comment: NB: The picture is unnecessary.

Comment: Then try having a look at the book by Evans and Gariepy on measure theory. There integration theory is developed in terms of lower and upper integrals, as you like. The point of measurability for a function, as it is measurability for a set, is that upper and lower sum coincide, at least in the nonnegative case.