# Definition of Lebesgue integral from Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Note that Rudin defines Lebesgue integral for function $f$ which is *measurable*. Is measurability is important here? What about if we'll define $(3)$ also for non-measurable function $f$?

Comment: The RHS of (3) is always defined, so there is no obstacle to define for every nonnegative $f$. But not much is gained by it. I think the restriction is there in order to get a nice theory (linearity, MCT etc.). Moreover the restriction is not very painful (it's hard to find functions that are *not* measurable).

Comment: @drhab, I am asking what problems would be if $(3)$ is defined for non-measurable functions?

Comment: What means that RHS of (3) is always defined?

Comment: In (3) the supremum mentioned on the right hand side of $=$ is properly defined for *every* nonnegative function $f$. That's all I am saying.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1081021/27978.