# What is the integral of the indicator function of VITALI?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

For a positive function $f$, the Lebesgue integral is the supremum of the integral of all simple functions below $f$. So if $f$ is the indicator function for the VITALI set, the lebesgue integral for it must exist. But in general, the integral of an indicator function of a set is the measure of that set. But VITALI is unmeasurable!?

Answer (score 2):

Any measurable subset $U$ of Vitali's set $V$ has measure zero. Therefore, if you take the supremum of the integrals of simple functions not larger than the indicator of vitali's set, their integrals are zero, and so is the supremum.

If $U\subset V$ is measurable, then for an enumeration $q_i$ of the rationals we have $U+q_i\pmod{1}$ disjoint for different $i$'s, measurable and of the same measure. Therefore $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\nu(U)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\nu(U+q_i\pmod{1})=\nu(\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}(U+q_i\pmod{1}))\leq\nu([0,1])=1$. Therefore $\nu(U)=0$.

Comment: If you don't require the integrand to be measurable, you get an inconsistent integral. Afaic, the Lebesgue integral is supposed to be countably additive. Consider indicators translated by rationals, $f_n:=1_{(U + q_i) (\mod 1)}$. Then $\int \sum_n f_n = \sum_n \int f_n$ does _not_ seem to hold: the lhs is at least $1$, while every summand on the rhs is $0$ (according to what you write), so is the sum. I am not 100% sure though. My statements are indirectly supported by the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081021).