# If we extend the usual Lebesgue integral on R to non-measurable functions, find an example of linearity failing.

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was wondering why we don't define the integral of a non-measurable, nonnegative function $f$ as follows:

$$
\int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu = \sup_{s \in S} \int_X s \,\mathrm{d}\mu
$$
where $S = \{ s : E \to [0, \infty) \mid s\le f, s \text{ is simple} \}$.

This answer answered my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1081030/471112. An example of linearity failing is given when $\mathbb R$ is given the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, the measure $\mu(\mathbb R) = 1$. Now define $f = 1 - g = \chi_{[0,1]}$. Then,

$$ 0 + 0 = \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu  + \int g \, \mathrm{d}\mu \ne \int f + g\, \mathrm{d}\mu = \int 1 \, \mathrm{d}\mu = 1. $$

This is all fine, but I'm not convinced by this example that we can't avoid this issue when we work with a sufficiently rich measure space (such as that of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, which I now refer to as $\mu$).

One idea I had was letting $V$ be a Vitali set, $f = \chi_{V\cap[0,1]}, g = \chi_{[0,1]\setminus V}$. (Please answer with a better example if there is one, I'm not so attached to this idea).

I managed to prove that $\int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu = 0 $, as any measurable subset of $V \cap [0,1]$ has measure 0 (if it has positive measure, the rational translates will also have positive measure, it would follow that $\mu ([0,1]) = \infty$, a contradiction ). I couldn't make any progress with calculating $\int g \, \mathrm{d}\mu$.

Comment: It is a well known result that a function $f\in L_1$ iff there is a sequence of elementary (simple) functions $\phi_n$ such that $\|f-\phi_n\|_1\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow 0$. In fact, If you consider only elementary functions, $L_1$ is basically the completion of the space of elementary functions under the psudonorm $\|f\|_1$. This all says that you can't do better than considering functions that are Lebesgue measurable, in the sense that $f$ can be approximated by Borel measurable functions with the norm $\|\;\|_1$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Could I ask you to spell it out a bit more? I've spent a while trying to understand your comment. I can see in one direction, to show the $\int f + g = \int f + \int g$ you can use simple function approximations for $f$ and $g$, and then linearity with simple functions is easy to see. Not sure why linearity can't hold when no such approximation is possible.

Comment: All that takes some effort. The key is to notice for instance that the outer measure used by Carathepdory in only countably additive on a $\sigma$-algebra than contains the Borel sets and that, believing in the axiom of choice, there are sets that are not measurable (in the sense of Caratheodory)

Comment: @OliverDíaz After I've given it some time to sit, I think I understand what you are getting at. However, in textbooks, $|| f - \phi_n ||$ wouldn't be defined unless we knew already that $|f - \phi_n|$ is measurable right? So this reasoning seems circular.

Comment: Not necessarily. it is possible to defined, as in how outer measures are defined, a "mean" $\|\;\|^*$ for every numeric function $f$ (measurable or not) by extending  first a mean on the elementary functions )simple functions for example) and then extending this to supreme of sequences of  elementary functions  and then using infimum of functions that ar supremum of elementary functions (this is the Daniell-Stone approach to integration). In any event, the Caratheodry method you are most familiar tell you what the right sets (end hence what elementary functions) are.